# Pass object through dataTransfer

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a native object through javascript's event.dataTransfer for drag and drop. I'm writing the front end editor portion of a CMS, and want users to be able to drag and drop elements (of many different types, ranging from files to images to snippets of HTML to just about anything). That's why I want to pass a real object, so I can attach data to it to specify things that will be necessary in order to know how to render it.

One workaround is to use jQuery's .data() to attach an object to something else on the page, and then simply pass the selector string in setData... but I don't particularly enjoy that hack.

This could also be solved with jQuery UI's draggable/droppable (and I'm not totally opposed to using any libraries), but since the dropzone is in an iframe, this is a actually a documented bug in the latest jQuery UI (1.10.2). Also, I would strongly prefer to do it natively if possible. There are already enough libraries in this app.

Here's the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/AHnh8/

```
var foo = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};

$dragme.on("dragstart", function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("foo", foo);
});

$dropzone.on("dragenter", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
$dropzone.on("dragover", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
$dropzone.on("drop", function(e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("foo")); // [Object object]
    console.log(typeof e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("foo")); // string
});
```

Now, after reading the specs, I totally understand why this fails. What I don't understand, is how to ultimately achieve what I want.

Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to stringify the data before sending it and JSON.parse the data upon receiving.

Comment: if the object you intend to pass is a DOM element then pass its `id` instead and then resolve it in your `dragover` handler; if the element does not have an id then you can set it programmatically with `el.id = 42` or use some other reliable identifier.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should pass the object to `JSON.stringify` before using `setData` because you can only store strings.

```
var j = JSON.stringify(foo);
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("foo", j);
```

And the other way round you have to reconvert the string to an object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("foo"));
console.log("foo is:", obj);
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aNErc/2/) working Fiddle

Comment: I had also considered this after I posted, though I still feel like there should be a way to pass an object?

Comment: i don't think there is a way. but you can add a global array where you store your data and then just pass the key to `set/getData`. Maybe it is faster for larger objects

Comment: Yeah I proposed that idea in the initial question. Was really hoping there was a way to pass a real object somehow. Seems kind of odd that that wouldn't be included in the drag n drop spec. I guess I'll just settle for the stringify or the global array...

Comment: I think this way is quite inefficient in this case. Encoding/decoding processes are extra overhead and the object will be duplicated unnecessarily. A temp global array seems the best way to handle this problem momentarily.

Comment: Unless you are dropping massive JSON objects,  I don't see how this could be inefficient. This way you can also drop things from other tabs!

Comment: It's not just the json encode/decode overhead. The more important thing is you loose the reference to the original object, so you can't change it easily. It is an issue in Vuejs for example, where everything is based on data (objects, arrays) and it would be convinient to directly reference them in drag and drop operations.

Comment: I had to remove the "originalEvent" reference.  And then everything worked.  Out of interest where is that coming from?

Comment: The first parameter is not a key but mime type like 'text/plain', seems like you use key name as mime type see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData

Answer (score 6):

Maybe what I am about to suggest is wrong (if so I will be happy to hear why ).
Why not set a variable in the dragstart listener to reference what you need, for example:

```
//global variable
var obj;

//set the global variable to wahtever you wish in the dragstart:
$dragme.on("dragstart", function(e) {
    obj = foo;
    //or even obj = document.getElementById("some element's id");
});

//use this obj in the drop listener.
$dropzone.on("drop", function(e) {
    obj.doWahtEver();
});
```

Comment: bc globals = :( .. There are plenty of trivial workarounds like this. I originally posted the question because I wanted to know if you could pass an object through dataTransfer. It turns out you can't.

Comment: @Kabir, yet it's more correct way then serialize/deserialize, from the docs you should be able to see that fromat of data is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString