# How to get data as Object from dataTransfer?

Tags: javascript

I do the following:

```
const blockOrField  = new Block();
ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", blockOrField);
```

When I get data in another place:

```
cosnt data = e.dataTransfer.getData("data");
```

I get `data` as `[object Object]` instead real instrance.

Before passing to data I see that it is instance:

```
 if (blockOrField instanceof FieldDefinition) {
      alert("works");
  }

ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", blockOrField);
```

I know it should be serialized to string JSON, but I have complicated instance with composition.

Comment: Does `setData` function in the same way as `localStorage`?
If so, you might want to `JSON.stringify` the data while setting it.

Comment: No I dont need serialize, I need pass it as instance class

Comment: It converts instance to string: `console.log(typeof e.dataTransfer.getData("data"));`

Comment: This QA could be related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839649/pass-object-through-datatransfer

Comment: I know, but do you know difference between instance class and plain object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [setData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) it specifically says "A DOMString representing the data to add to the drag object.". So you are out of luck trying to store an object reference there.

What I would do here is create a another object somewhere and store the needed reference there with an id.

```
const dataTransferCache = {};

function onDragStart(ev) {
    const block = new Block();
    const id = GetRandomId(); // Just get an id somehow
    dataTransferCache[id] = block;
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("data", id);
}

function onDragEnd(ev) {
    const id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("data");
    const block = dataTransferCache[id];
    delete dataTransferCache[id]; // Remove the value again
}
```

This would even support multi touch dragging if that is somehow needed. If this needs to be shared between components you could simply put the dataTransferCache in a separate file and include a reference to in in both components.